# The value of the local variable word is not used

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method that has a Scanner as a parameter. The purpose of the method is to count the number of words in a file and return that number.  Here is the method:

```
public static int getWordCount(Scanner inputFile) 
        throws FileNotFoundException  {
    int wordCount = 0;      
    while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String word = inputFile.next();         
        wordCount++;                
    }
    return wordCount;       
}
```

The method works fine, however I get a "The value of the local variable word is not used" warning which I would like to get rid of.  I understand why I am getting the warning, however, as far as I know, I need the

```
String word = inputFile.next();
```

to move the pointer through the file.  I can suppress the warning, however, I figure that there is probably a better way of doing what I am trying to do. I can only use Scanner class to read the file.

Comment: just call `inputFile.next()` without storing it into the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine, but the warning is given because you only assign to `word` and never read from it. Try just leaving out the assignment and using just `inputFile.next()` instead with simply not saving the result.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know I could do that.  For some reason I thought I had to assign it to a variable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anytime. If this answer solved you problem, please accept it so this question can be considered answered.

Comment: Yes sir as soon as it will let me I will check it.  For some reason it's making me wait.